# Which Grub to use for a custom portable boot image?

Tags: linux, kernel, grub, live-usb, livecd

I would like to make a bootable USB/Floopy/LiveCD with linux kernel and Grub. 
After booting to that USB/Floopy/LiveCD using VirtualBox or directly, it will show my own customized Grub screen and then it will execute my C or Pascal application.

I was trying to [download grub](ftp://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/grub/) but I am not sure which one I should use. Is there any issue to download the correct version of Grub such as for 32-Bit or 64-Bit downloads are different?

Which Grub should I download to get started with my own customized bootable image?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you please edit the question to more fully describe what you are trying to accomplish and what your different scenarios are?

Comment: @Caleb: Please check kindly.

Comment: Thanks for updating. I can at least make out what the question is about now. See my answer for why I think you are starting at the wrong end of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only two versions of grub listed there, the 1x series (most recent being 0.97) and the 2x series (most recent being 1.99). Both can be customized and used for your purpose. The 1x series has more standard compatibility with old hardware and distros, but we the 2x series is coming along nicly and many major distros are switching to it. 32bit vs 64 bit architecture is not a consideration for grub at this stage of the boot process, that won't come into play until you launch a kernel. Since grub doesn't do much it's happy to run on a generic set of cpu instructions.

But really you shouldn't be starting with grub and working up form there ... that will be a long road. You should probably start with some already arranged livecd image and work backwards to pare it down to just run your program on boot. This will save you all kinds of trouble. Pick some lightweight livecd that you like and get it's source, then start stripping out the bits you don't need and adding your program.